# IMPORTXML Google Sheets Formula to import data on web

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I am having a hard time getting the xpath for this link.

Pls help get the right xpath of the upload and download speed values. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

there isn't such XPath that would work because IMPORTXML does not support scrapping JavaScript elements. see:

[image]

workaround is to use different non-JS site